# Is it Possible to fetch the lat-long of the current location in iPhone for continuous

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

I know that it is possible to fetch the lat-lng of the current location. But i want to make it to fetch continuosly for iphone. 
So is it Possible ? If Possible then How its Possible. . 
Please Guide me regarding it. . .
Thanks.

Comment: If you call startUpdatingLocation it gets the user location and keeps updating it unless you call stopUpdatingLocation, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `CoreLocation` framework to access location information about your user. You will need to instantiate a `CLLocationManager` object and call the `asynchronous startUpdatingLocation` message. You will get callbacks with the user's location via the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` that you supply.

See code Samples

[Get the User Location in iPhone App](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-get-current-location-iphone-user/)

[Getting the User’s Location](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html)

[A CoreLocation Tutorial](http://mobileorchard.com/hello-there-a-corelocation-tutorial/)